# com.avaje.ebean.model cannot be resolved play framework 2.6

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

As per documentation I have added:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "4.0.2")
```

To `project/plugins.sbt` file and then modified `build.sbt` to enable the Play Ebean plugin:

```
lazy val myProject = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)
```

and `ebean.default = ["models.*"]` to `conf/application.conf` file.

I have done all the steps like `clean` project, rebuild, reopen the project. Still, it is unable to solve `com.avaje.ebean.model`.

Please help me regarding this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of this Ebean release:

https://github.com/ebean-orm/ebean/releases/tag/ebean-10.1.1

> **This release changes the package to `io.ebean`**. This means the enhancement agent, maven plugins etc all where also updated and released (as 10.1.1)

And play-ebean 4.0.2 is using Ebean 10.3.1, as you can see here:

https://github.com/playframework/play-ebean/blob/4.0.2/build.sbt#L7

So, you need to import `io.ebean.model` instead of `com.avaje.ebean.model`.